# Is the 'SUIDGuard' patch safe to implement?

Tags: known-vulnerabilities, macos, patching, privilege-escalation, kernel

Can someone who really knows what they're looking at advise whether the patch [published here](https://github.com/sektioneins/SUIDGuard) by Stefan Esser is in fact safe to install?

While I'm very concerned that Apple haven't published an official patch yet (especially now that I've tried Esser's [example myself](https://twitter.com/i0n1c/status/623727538234368000)), this is a *kernel extension* so I'm equally hesitant to just rush into implementing it.

Note: I'm grateful to Esser for drawing attention to this and am not implying his fix might by 'malicious' (particularly as it's openly published). I just want an informed answer on exactly how it works and whether there are any side-effects.

Comment: This may be the wrong site for this type of question. Perhaps serverfault.com would be better?

Comment: @"Neil Smithline": Isn't the core of this question a risk evaluation question? Do you think colleagues on this group are unqualified to analyze code security?

Comment: @NeilSmithline this directly impacts the security of *any* computer running OS X 10.10.X - that includes MacBooks, iMacs etc etc

Comment: Alright. Works for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first important thing is to *think* about the meaning of this security hole. This is a *local privilege escalation*: *if* an attacker can get to run code of his choosing on the machine, with "normal" privileges, *then* that attacker can use this hole to obtain more extended privileges on that machine.

In general, for a desktop system, when attackers can run their own code on your machine, they have already won. On a desktop systems, your own actions, as a "normal user", are all done as process running, from the point of view of the kernel, with the privileges attached to your user account. If an attacker manages to run his own code, it will be through subverting one of your applications, or making you unwittingly run a seemingly honest screensaver or something like that. Privileges attached to your account are sufficient to plunder the contents of all your files, display spurious ads, hijack your network connections, and generally steal your whole life. Also obtaining root privileges on the machine does not substantially increase the scope of the disaster, though it may make life easier for the attacker.

Moreover, as a "normal user", you *already* have ways to obtain root privileges, and you do use them on a regular basis -- e.g. to authorize an update of the Flash plugin. The updater system will ask you for your password and use it to request and obtain root privileges. An attacker who can run code under your name just has to mimic a Flash update to display the popup and obtain the privileges. In that sense, the new vulnerability is irrelevant *for a desktop system*. Correspondingly, there is no hurry in fixing it.

---

Privilege escalation holes make a lot more sense on **shared servers**, where several users who can potentially be hostile to each other share the same hardware, and the  OS must arbitrate between users and protect them from each other. Shared servers are an old model, back when we were talking of [mainframes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mainframe_computer). An information security professional who is now in his forties must have been exposed to that model while he was a student, in the 1980s or 1990s. At that time, computer students were typically using terminals in some shared computer room, and accessing one or a few central servers with a Unix-like operating systems. Privilege escalation was then a much sought after grail.

This rarely applies nowadays. Right now, in 2015, when there is shared hardware, users are granted virtual machines, not simply shell accounts. There *still* are places where servers are shared in the old way, but they are a vanishing species. If your OS X machines are servers that are used that way, with users that you cannot all trust (or that do not trust each other), then yes, the privilege escalation hole is a big concern. However, chances are that this is not the case.

---

Assuming that you still want to fix the hole quickly by installing Esser's patch, then you have two points to consider:

1. You are, basically, inserting in your machine, with "kernel privileges", a piece of code downloaded off the Internet. This entails a rather heavy dose of trust. You must be sure that the *Internet persona* that appears to go by the name of "Stefan Esser" is trustworthy enough, and that nobody else could alter the patch where it is stored or while you download it.

   How would some "guarantee" by another *Internet persona*, even with an awesome avatar, create some extra trust ?

   You could, though, get the source code, audit it, then compile it yourself. But if you feel that you can do that, then you do not need any help from a StackExchange site; you already know enough.
2. The patch changes the behaviour of the machine, conceptually to make it "better" (or "safer"), but a change is always a change and may break things. It is possible that some application developer, somewhere, had noticed that some DYLD_* environment variables survive through SUID execution, and actually used it for some functionality (without necessarily noticing that this has security implications). While the patch appears to be harmless enough (at least from what I see in the source code -- but can you trust *me* ?), I cannot exclude the possibility that it impacts the behaviour of some parts of the OS or applications.

Comment: Your response is ten paragraphs. Only three of which are relevant (the ones under `1.`). In point of fact, the opinion of someone with an awesome avatar on here really **does** matter and establish trust, if they have a track record of answering questions well (so, we know they're qualified and, more often than not, fail to answer maliciously), and they audit the code.

Comment: If I can't trust the community on here to give sound security advice and monitor itself, and have multiple people with high rep audit code and reach a consensus, then there sort of isn't a point to the site at all. This site gives security advice. If that wasn't a problem last week, why is it a problem now?

Comment: I don't deal with trust. I provide _information_ and _explanations_ -- to be used by human brains who like to _think_. Basing any kind of trust on anything as fuzzy as a semi-anonymous social media, however well-organized, would be quite insane, and was already last week, last month and last year.

Comment: Speaking of which, the seven paragraphs that you dismiss so lightly _are_ relevant: a notion of risk is meaningless if you do not know what you would gain through the installation of the patch; and these paragraphs tell you that (and the answer being: about nothing).

Comment: That's all well and good, but if you audited the code (which, from cursory examination, is only ~100 lines) you could probably give a pretty good explanation of what it's doing and why it makes sense / doesn't make sense to use it. And then, if someone else read the code and disagreed, they could add that in a comment (over which you'd have no control) and the community as a whole could read the conversation, look over the code, and vote accordingly.

Comment: "Basing any kind of trust on anything as fuzzy as a semi-anonymous social media, however well-organized, would be quite insane, and was already last week, last month and last year." Alright. Then how, exactly, do you decide who to trust and what software to trust? What is the utility of this site, for someone with a question, if they cannot trust the larger community to endorse justified answers and decry unjustified ones?

Comment: I guess my main annoyance with this answer is that, clearly, you didn't want to audit the code- neither do I. Auditing code is a mixed bag and I'm tired. But, not having audited it, I don't feel qualified to answer the question as asked.

Comment: I certainly don't want to make audits when there are people around who will take my ramblings as _guarantees_. That's quite the opposite of what I want to achieve. I want people to think by themselves. Not to wail and open their beaks for some divine spirit of the "community" to provide them with pre-digested gospel. What I _do_ want to do, though, is to point out that the question can be avoided by realising that there is most probably nothing to actually _gain_ in installing the patch, thus making the "no install" course by definition the safer one.

Comment: If you're going to respond to the OP's specific situation, always do that after responding to the question as asked. Because the people who reach this question aren't going to all be in the OP's exact situation. Some may be running servers, and want to know.

Comment: As evidenced by my responses here, no one is taking your ramblings as guarantees. A code audit doesn't simply have to output the response "safe" v. "not safe". It could walk through the code (which is somewhat cryptic) and explain each part, with links to relevant Apple documentation. It could deal purely in facts. It's infeasible to audit all the code that runs on a given machine, so at the end of the day you need to trust **someone** to have done (at least some of) that for you, or at least done enough of it to explain the code and make understanding it happen that much faster.

Comment: Plenty of security software can be viewed as "a piece of code downloaded off the Internet". And you're right that "This entails a rather heavy dose of trust". But you posit that "You must be sure that the Internet persona that appears to go by the name of "Stefan Esser" is trustworthy enough", and that's insane. You don't need to trust the code's author; you just need to trust the code. And that's easier if you have a framework within which to understand what the code's doing. I don't need to trust the people who wrote `echo` if I have the source code and relevant manpages.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26169/discussion-between-parthian-shot-and-thomas-pornin).